# How to initialize a compound literal with a value of the same type?

Tags: c, struct, compound-literals

for example:

```
typedef struct S { int i; char c; } S;

#define MAKE_CLITERAL(T) ((typeof(T)) {T})

int main()
{
    S s = {.i = 500, .c = 'a'};

    S s2 = MAKE_CLITERAL(s); // doesn't compile
}
```

I want the macro `MAKE_CLITERAL` to turn any value into a compound literal.

such that doing something like `MAKE_CLITERAL( 10 )` and `MAKE_CLITERAL( s )` both make compound literals of their type.

I tried doing this:

```
#define MAKE_CLITERAL(T) ( (typeof(T)){} = T );
```

but it doesn't behave exactly like a compound literal, so this doesn't work:

```
&MAKE_CLITERAL(s); // compiler says this is an rvalue
```

Is there a way to initialize a compound literal by using a value of the same type?

Comment: If you have a previously defined struct, you don't need a compound literal, ie. `s2 = s;`

Comment: Try this `S s2 = s;` and if you want to initialize individual members (or may be some selected members only) then `S s2 = {.i = s.i, .c = s.c};`.

Comment: @H.S. The reason I can't do that is I have a macro that generates compound literals from a value. I've edited my question to show what I mean.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your code expands to `S s = {.i = 500, .c = 'a'}; ((typeof(s)) {s});` which seems meaningless.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I want the macro `MAKE_CLITERAL` to take any value and turn it into a compound literal. Be it an integer, a struct, or any other type.

Comment: So you want `(s){ some_int, some_char }`  - but for any type, no matter how many members?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes,

Comment: Don't you think you'll make yourself a disservice if you "macro" your away from clarity? C is rather strict when it comes to types. The more macro-magic you add to it, the more odd it'll become.

Comment: how is it not clear? I feel like `MAKE_CLITERAL( value )` is descriptive enough.

Comment: It may be for you. I have absolutely no idea what `MAKE_CLITERAL` will do.

Comment: I think you should try to clarify (in the question) what you actually expect to happen. It's really not clear at all. And I won't even ask about the mystery `&` in your example.

Comment: @pmacfarlane the `&` is to show that the workaround of doing this: `#define MAKE_CLITERAL(T) ( (typeof(T)){} = T );` doesn't work like compound literal, because compound literals are lvalues

Comment: Does `S s2 = s;` work for you?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I've edited my question to better explain what I mean.

Comment: @ikegami no. `MAKE_CLITERAL( 10 )` wouldn't work. It'd be an rvalue in the way you made it.

Comment: @ikegami compound literals are lvalues

Comment: @ikegami, you **can** do `&"abc"`.

Comment: I think you're fighting the very nature ot the C language itself. It does not support templates/generics, and trying to hack your way around that probably won't do what you want, so you're probably better off either using a language that supports the design you want, or changing your design to use the features C does have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the object into an untagged struct type created within the compound literal.

```
#define MAKE_CLITERAL(T) (struct { typeof(T) t; } ) { T }.t
```

Comment: this works well! but is there a way to make it work with arrays? or is that just not possible? 

for example:
`int arr[5]; MAKE_CLITERAL(arr);`

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi, it should work with arrays. Arrays cannot be assigned in C.

Comment: I'm not trying to assign to an array type. All I need is for the data of the array to go into the literal and be an rvalue. It doesn't seem to be possible in C tho. For example: `int x = MAKE_CLITERAL( arr )[0]`

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi, indeed. The problem is initialization of one array with a value of other array. Probably some magic spell with `memcpy()` would work but I need some time to figure it out.